# Vuex not properly working from iframe in multiple layouts

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two layouts, default and main.

The default layout is for the page view and the main layout is an empty wrapper without components.

The page with main layout is loaded as an iframe inside the page with the default layout.

When i change state inside the main layout i can listen to and get the changes whilst outside the main layout in the default layout i can't listen to and get the changes from inside the iframe/default layout.

Any idea why? Maybe because of the iframe, or because the Nuxt instance is loaded in both layouts separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway i found the answer, the problem was that the iframe has a different state check how to sync them here https://github.com/L-Chris/vuex-iframe-sync

Comment: Can you clarify how you got the `vuex-iframe-sync` package running in nuxt?

Comment: No sorry, too long ago